# java - Input 2 integer arrays and print alternating elements

Tags: java, arrays, printing, merge, alternating

Conditions:

1. both arrays must be in order or error message
2. the first array must be as long as or longer than the second or error message
3. if the first is longer than the second it must continue to print the first

Example: given setF[] = 1,2,3,4,8 and setS[] =5,6,7 it prints 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8

The Problem With My Code: It will print and alternate fine, but will not continue to print the first areay if it's longer.

full code (I apologize for slightly messy formatting. The website screwed it up a little bit):

```
package mergearrays;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MergeArrays {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //variables
    boolean done = false;
    boolean error = false;
    int inpval = 0;
    int i = 0; //will be setF.length
    int j = 0; //will be setS.length
    //arrays
    int [] vals = new int[20000]; 

    //ask user
    System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000      values, enter zero or a negative number to quit");

    //input array
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(!done) {
        inpval = scan.nextInt();
        if (inpval > 0) {
            vals[i] = inpval;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            done = true;
        }
    }
    done = false;
    System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter zero or a negative number to quit");
    while(!done) {
        inpval = scan.nextInt();
        if (inpval > 0) {
            vals[j+i+1] = inpval;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            done = true;
        }
    }
    //new arrays
    int [] setF = new int[10000];
    int [] setS = new int[10000];

    //copy vals into setF and setS
    System.arraycopy(vals, 0, setF, 0, i);
    System.arraycopy(vals, i+1, setS, 0, i+j+1);

    //check for order
    for (int p = 0; p < i - 1; p++) {
        if (setF[p] > setF[p+1]) {
            error = true;
        break;
        }
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < j - 1; b++) {
        if (setS[b] > setS[b+1]) {
             error = true;
        break;
        }
    }
    //print first array
    System.out.print("\n First Array: ");
    for(int q = 0; q < i; q++) {
        System.out.print(setF[q] + " ");
    }
    //print second array
    System.out.print("\n Second Array: ");
    for(int m = 0; m < j; m++) {
        System.out.print(setS[m] + " ");
    }

    //print the final set
    if(i >= j && error == false){
        System.out.print("\n Merged Array: ");
        for(int n = 0; n <= i+j; n++) {
            if(setF[n] != 0 && setS[n] !=0) {
                if(n <= j) {
                    System.out.print(setF[n] + " ");
                    System.out.print(setS[n] + " ");
                }
                else if(n > j && n <= i){
                    System.out.print(setF[n] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //error message
    else {
        System.out.print("\n ERROR: Array not in correct order");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you see the answer?

Answer (score 1):

the reason it didn't continue to print for you if the first array is longer lies in this line of code:

```
if (setF[n] != 0 && setS[n] != 0) {
```

You continued to print only if both of the array at the same position were zero. You should check here 'OR' not 'AND'. In addition, after changing that condition to 'OR', the ifs inside need to be changed as well, because the indexes are not correct. As follows:

```
System.out.print("\n Merged Array: ");
for (int n = 0; n <= i + j; n++) {
    if (setF[n] != 0 || setS[n] != 0) {
        if (n < j) {
            System.out.print(setF[n] + " ");
            System.out.print(setS[n] + " ");
        } else if (n < i) {
            System.out.print(setF[n] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I would have solved it in a different way, and I can guide you to if you need some help. Anyways, Hope this helps...